# Flip array index with sed

Tags: sed

I have some java code declaring a 2d array that I want to flip.
Content is like:

```
zData[0][0] = 198;
zData[0][1] = 198;
zData[0][2] = 198;
    ...
```

And I want to flip indices to have

```
zData[0][0] = 198;
zData[1][0] = 198;
zData[2][0] = 198;
```

So I tried doing it with sed:

```
sed -r 's#zData[([0-9]*)][([0-9]*)]#zData[\2][\1]#g' DataSample1.java
```

But unfortunately sed says:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: Unmatched ) or \)
```

Might the string "zData" hold kind of flag or option?

I tried not using the -r option but I have the same kind of message for:

```
sed 's#zData[\(\[\0\-\9\]\*\)][\(\[\0\-\9\]\*\)]#zData[\2][\1]#g' DataSample1.java
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples:

```bash
$ sed -r 's/(zData)(\[[^]]+])(\[[^]]+])/\1\3\2/' file
zData[0][0] = 198;
zData[1][0] = 198;
zData[2][0] = 198;
```

Regexplanation:

```bash
# Match
(zData)     # Capture the variable name we want to transpose
(           # Start capture group for first index  
\[          # Opening bracket escaped to mean literal [
[^]]+       # One or more none ] characters i.e the digits 
]           # The closing literal ] doesn't need escaping here.
)           # Close the capture
(\[[^]]+])  # Same regexp as before for the second index 
# Replace
\1\3\2      # Switch the indexes but rearranging the 2nd and 3rd capture groups
```

Note: Switch `\[[^]]+]` to if it is clearer `\[[0-9]+]` for you, so instead of saying match an opening square bracket followed by one or more none-closing brackets followed by a closing bracket you are saying match an opening square bracket followed by one or more digit followed by a closing bracket.

Comment: That works, thanks. Can you explain the (\[[^]]+]) form? Why are there two [ and three ]? I am also surprised by ]+.

Answer (score 2):

Try that one:

```
sed 's#\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]\+\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)\(\[[^]*]\]\)\(.*$\)#\1\3\2\4#'
```

It adds four captures for the variable name, the first index, the second index and the rest and then switches order.

**Edit:** @Sudo_O's solution with extended regular expressions is much more readable. Thx for that! Nevertheless, on some systems `sed -r` may not be available, since it is not part of  [basic POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html).

Comment: That works, thanks. As for sudo o solution, I am kind of suprised by the \(\[[^]]*\]\), mainly because there are two [ and three ]. Can you explain?

Comment: Note: POSIX friendly `sed 's/\(zData\)\(\[[^]]*]\)\(\[[^]]*]\)/\1\3\2/'`